# Error creating queue with WebSphere MQ API

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I trying to create queues using PCF command in the WebSphere API as detailed in `$MQM_HOME/samp/pcf/samples/PCF_CreateQeue.java`. The creation fails when i add a description

```
command.addParameter(PCFConstants.MQCA_Q_DESC, "Created using MQMonitor");
```

I get the error: `com.ibm.mq.pcf.PCFException: MQJE001: Completion Code 2, Reason 3015 : MQRCCF_CFST_PARM_ID_ERROR`
Is there another way of setting the description, i'm using version 6 of the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the `addParameter` on the `PCFMessage` **should in a certain sequence** (stumbled on it). If i change the add parameters if works. This is not just for creating queues, but for channels as well.

```
command.addParameter(PCFConstants.MQCA_Q_NAME, qname);
command.addParameter(PCFConstants.MQIA_Q_TYPE, PCFConstants.MQQT_LOCAL);
command.addParameter(PCFConstants.MQCA_Q_DESC, qdesc);
command.addParameter(PCFConstants.MQIA_DEF_PERSISTENCE, PCFConstants.MQPER_PERSISTENT);
```

the above will execute without error.

```
command.addParameter(PCFConstants.MQCA_Q_NAME, qname);
command.addParameter(PCFConstants.MQCA_Q_DESC, qdesc);
command.addParameter(PCFConstants.MQIA_Q_TYPE, PCFConstants.MQQT_LOCAL);
command.addParameter(PCFConstants.MQIA_DEF_PERSISTENCE, PCFConstants.MQPER_PERSISTENT);
```

the above will fail after moving around the description.

I haven't seen it documented in the Java docs, and if thats the case i looks forward to some hide and seek.

Comment: I've ditched my initial answer and updated my response with links to the appropriate manuals.  What you tripped over is documented, just not in the Java manual.

Answer (score 2):

The [Commands page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.csqzac.doc/pc10620_.htm) in the PCF manual states that:

> The required parameters and the
>   optional parameters are listed. On
>   platforms other than z/OS®, the
>   parameters *must occur in the order*:
>
> 1. All required parameters, in the order stated, followed by
> 2. Optional parameters as required, in any order, unless specifically
>      noted in the PCF definition.

The section [Change, Copy and Create Queue](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.csqzac.doc/pc11160_.htm) lists the required parameters in the following order:

1. MQCA_Q_NAME
2. MQIA_Q_TYPE
3. Optional parameters, including QDesc

The same manual provides required parameters and their order for all PCF commands so no need to play hide-and-seek trying out parms and orders in the future.